# Finding layout of points on road?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, line, nominatim, points-to-line

The problem I'm trying to solve is finding layout of street lights on a street. The street lights can be arranged in the following layout: one-side, two-side opposite, staggered, or median, etc. as shown in the picture.

[image: Example of street lighting layouts]

I have latitude, longitude of street light points of several cities and I want to build a classifier that can determine the road lighting layout.

I thought of the following approach so far but I'm stuck at what should I do after a step.

1. Reverse geocode all the street light points using Nominatim and assign each one to a street_id using street name as well as get the OSM way id.
2. Use the OSM way id to obtain the polyline of the street.
3. Find out which points lie on which side of the polyline using Linear Referencing Toolbox in ArcGIS.
4. Find the distance between poles by calculating average distance to nearest neighbor on each side of the road.

I'm stuck here.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It's unclear which of your four steps you are stuck on, or is it on the next step?  In any event we will need much more precise details about what you have tried and where you are stuck for the step that you wish to ask about.